# How to handle multiple participant and their video/audio feed in twilio video conference in android?

Tags: android, twilio

```
I am using twilio video, i want to make a video conference app in android.

Peer to peer connection works fine, but 

1) how can i render/handle audio-video feed of more then one participant in a video room?

2) I am rendering the view of first participant as shown in video quickstart sdk and for more then one i tried inflating views by using participant array size. i have tried inflating views when 2nd participant(in a room that has the room creator and a participant) joins then all three mobile devices stuck and become totally unresponsive and i have to kill the app.

3) So how can i render lets say 4 participants(besides the room creator-local participant) and render their feeds accordingly in the order they
join the room and handle their removal or disconnection from the room?

The video quick start sample has a comment stating that currently only one participant is handled in the UI, i couldn't find any demo that shows how to handle multiple participants. Is there a way to do it?

Thanks.

here is my code
```

Videoactivity

Room listener

```
private Room.Listener roomListener() {
        return new Room.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onConnected(Room room) {
                localParticipant = room.getLocalParticipant();
                videoStatusTextView.setText("Connected to " + room.getName());
                Snackbar.make(connectActionFab,
                        "Local Participant name: " + room.getLocalParticipant().getIdentity(),
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
                setTitle(room.getName());
                for (RemoteParticipant remoteParticipant : room.getRemoteParticipants()) {
                    addRemoteParticipant(remoteParticipant);
                    break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onConnectFailure(Room room, TwilioException e) {
                videoStatusTextView.setText("Failed to connect");
                configureAudio(false);
                intializeUI();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDisconnected(Room room, TwilioException e) {
                localParticipant = null;
                videoStatusTextView.setText("Disconnected from " + room.getName());
                VideoActivity.this.room = null;
                // Only reinitialize the UI if disconnect was not called from onDestroy()
                if (!disconnectedFromOnDestroy) {
                    configureAudio(false);
                    intializeUI();
                    moveLocalVideoToPrimaryView();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onParticipantConnected(Room room, RemoteParticipant remoteParticipant) {
                if (thumbnailVideoView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    addRemoteParticipant(remoteParticipant);
                    Snackbar.make(connectActionFab,
                            "Participant array size " + room.getRemoteParticipants().size()
                                    + "Participant " + remoteParticipant.getIdentity() + "connected to room",
                            Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                } else {
                    addSecondRemoteParticipant(remoteParticipant);
                    Snackbar.make(connectActionFab,
                            "Participant array size " + room.getRemoteParticipants().size()
                                    + "Second Remote Participant " + remoteParticipant.getIdentity() + "connected to room",
                            Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                    Log.e(TAG, "onSecondParticipantConnected: " + room.getRemoteParticipants().size());
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onParticipantDisconnected(Room room, RemoteParticipant remoteParticipant) {

                Snackbar.make(connectActionFab,
                        "Participant array size " + room.getRemoteParticipants().size()
                                + "Participant " + remoteParticipant.getIdentity() + "disconnected to room",
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
                removeRemoteParticipant(remoteParticipant);


            }

            @Override
            public void onRecordingStarted(Room room) {

                Log.d(TAG, "onRecordingStarted");
            }

            @Override
            public void onRecordingStopped(Room room) {

                Log.d(TAG, "onRecordingStopped");
            }
        };
    }
```

Participant Listner

```
private RemoteParticipant.Listener remoteParticipantListener() {
        return new RemoteParticipant.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onAudioTrackPublished(RemoteParticipant remoteParticipant,
                                              RemoteAudioTrackPublication remoteAudioTrackPublication) {

                videoStatusTextView.setText("onAudioTrackPublished");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAudioTrackUnpublished(RemoteParticipant remoteParticipant,
                                                RemoteAudioTrackPublication remoteAudioTrackPublication) {
               videoStatusTextView.setText("onAudioTrackUnpublished");
            }

            @Override
            public void onDataTrackPublished(RemoteParticipant remoteParticipant,
                                             RemoteDataTrackPublication remoteDataTrackPublication) {
                             videoStatusTextView.setText("onDataTrackPublished");
            }

            @Override
            public void onDataTrackUnpublished(RemoteParticipant remoteParticipant,
                                               RemoteDataTrackPublication remoteDataTrackPublication) {
                    videoStatusTextView.setText("onDataTrackUnpublished");
            }

            @Override
            public void onVideoTrackPublished(RemoteParticipant remoteParticipant,
                                              RemoteVideoTrackPublication remoteVideoTrackPublication) {
                                  videoStatusTextView.setText("onVideoTrackPublished");
            }

            @Override
            public void onVideoTrackUnpublished(RemoteParticipant remoteParticipant,
                                                RemoteVideoTrackPublication remoteVideoTrackPublication) {
               videoStatusTextView.setText("onVideoTrackUnpublished");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAudioTrackSubscribed(RemoteParticipant remoteParticipant,
                                               RemoteAudioTrackPublication remoteAudioTrackPublication,
                                               RemoteAudioTrack remoteAudioTrack) {

                videoStatusTextView.setText("onAudioTrackSubscribed");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAudioTrackUnsubscribed(RemoteParticipant remoteParticipant,
                                                 RemoteAudioTrackPublication remoteAudioTrackPublication,
                                                 RemoteAudioTrack remoteAudioTrack) {

                videoStatusTextView.setText("onAudioTrackUnsubscribed");
            }

            @Override
            public void onDataTrackSubscribed(RemoteParticipant remoteParticipant,
                                              RemoteDataTrackPublication remoteDataTrackPublication,
                                              RemoteDataTrack remoteDataTrack) {

                videoStatusTextView.setText("onDataTrackSubscribed");
            }

            @Override
            public void onDataTrackUnsubscribed(RemoteParticipant remoteParticipant,
                                                RemoteDataTrackPublication remoteDataTrackPublication,
                                                RemoteDataTrack remoteDataTrack) {
               videoStatusTextView.setText("onDataTrackUnsubscribed");
            }

            @Override
            public void onVideoTrackSubscribed(RemoteParticipant remoteParticipant,
                                               RemoteVideoTrackPublication remoteVideoTrackPublication,
                                               RemoteVideoTrack remoteVideoTrack) {

                videoStatusTextView.setText("onVideoTrackSubscribed");

                if (thumbnailVideoView.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                    if(!ifFirstParticipantHasVideoFeed){
                        addRemoteParticipantVideo(remoteVideoTrack);
                        ifFirstParticipantHasVideoFeed=true;
                        Snackbar.make(connectActionFab,
                                "Participant array size " + room.getRemoteParticipants().size()
                                        + "Participant " + remoteParticipant.getIdentity() + "connected to room",
                                Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .setAction("Action", null).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        if(ifFirstParticipantHasVideoFeed){
                            addSecondRemoteParticipantVideo(remoteVideoTrackPublication.getRemoteVideoTrack());
                        }
                    }

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onVideoTrackUnsubscribed(RemoteParticipant remoteParticipant,
                                                 RemoteVideoTrackPublication remoteVideoTrackPublication,
                                                 RemoteVideoTrack remoteVideoTrack) {
               videoStatusTextView.setText("onVideoTrackUnsubscribed");
                removeParticipantVideo(remoteVideoTrack);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAudioTrackEnabled(RemoteParticipant remoteParticipant,
                                            RemoteAudioTrackPublication remoteAudioTrackPublication) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAudioTrackDisabled(RemoteParticipant remoteParticipant,
                                             RemoteAudioTrackPublication remoteAudioTrackPublication) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onVideoTrackEnabled(RemoteParticipant remoteParticipant,
                                            RemoteVideoTrackPublication remoteVideoTrackPublication) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onVideoTrackDisabled(RemoteParticipant remoteParticipant,
                                             RemoteVideoTrackPublication remoteVideoTrackPublication) {

            }
        };
    }
```

To add second remote participant i have used below methods

```
private void addSecondRemoteParticipant(RemoteParticipant remoteParticipant) {
        secondRemoteParticipantIdentity = remoteParticipant.getIdentity();
        videoStatusTextView.setText("Second RemoteParticipant " + remoteParticipantIdentity + " joined");
        Log.e(TAG, "addSecondRemoteParticipant: " + remoteParticipant.getIdentity());


    if (remoteParticipant.getRemoteVideoTracks().size() > 0) {
        RemoteVideoTrackPublication remoteVideoTrackPublication =
                remoteParticipant.getRemoteVideoTracks().get(0);


        if (remoteVideoTrackPublication.isTrackSubscribed()) {
            addSecondRemoteParticipantVideo(remoteVideoTrackPublication.getRemoteVideoTrack());
        }
    }

    remoteParticipant.setListener(remoteParticipantListener());
}


private void addSecondRemoteParticipantVideo(RemoteVideoTrack remoteVideoTrack) {
    VideoView video = new VideoView(VideoActivity.this);
    video.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(300, 300));
    video.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    video.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
    linearVideoParent.addView(video);


    remoteVideoTrack.addRenderer(video);

i have checked in debugging till here, but still i some how video is not getting rendered in the view i created.

    Snackbar.make(connectActionFab, "added second participant's video",
            Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

I have tried inflating a view run time when second remote participant connects but i can't get the video rendered in it.

It seems that there is a time gap between 
1) when participant is added/joins the room (which we can listen to from
participant listener)

and

2) When the participant's video track is subscribed (onVideotrackSubscribed)

Comment: It's definitely possible to do this. What have you tried so far, including the code, and what is going wrong with it?

Comment: can you share your mail address? i'll send the code. I have used this https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-android

Comment: This is stack overflow, I'd recommend you share the code here so that the community can help.

Comment: @philnash here you go i have shared code

Comment: Which `VideoView` have you imported to that file, the standard Android one or the [Twilio `VideoView`](https://twilio.github.io/twilio-video-android/docs/latest/)?

Comment: its twilio video view

Comment: I have manged to render the third participant, now i am facing issues in removing the participant.
  
if (remoteVideoTrackPublication.isTrackSubscribed()) 
{
removeSecondParticipantVideo(remoteVideoTrackPublication.getRemoteVideoTrack());
}

i am getting false at this condition, says that participant video is not subscribed so i cant remove its view, is it okay if i remove the view with checking this condition?

Comment: How are you keeping track of the `remoteVideoTrackPublication`? Is it possible that `remoteVideoTrackPublication` is one that has already been removed and the one you want is elsewhere?

Comment: hi @philnash can you please help me too i have same issue

Comment: Can I suggest you check out the QuickStart app, which can handle multiple participants: https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-android. Also, for a more complex example, check out this collaboration app: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video-app-android

Comment: @philnash i already check  github.com/twilio/twilio-video-app-android but it's in kotlin , my coding is in java

Comment: @philnash my issue is only that 1st and last person video is feeded with each other

Comment: The other example is in Java though. And I’m not an Android developer, so I don’t have much to add. Another alternative is to ask a new question, share your code and the specific problem you are having and see if there’s anyone else that can answer.

Comment: ok thank you  i will post a question as well